# Gradient color for data in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, color

I have a list [here](https://files.fm/u/g3rhb28p?), which I plot with `ListPlot`. I wish to color the data points using a special gradient. For example, in the interval $[4, 6]$ (along the `y` axis), the desired effect is a gradient of `Red` to `LightRed`. And for interval $[-1, 3.9]$, a gradient of `Green` is desired. How can I reach this goal?

[image]

To clarify my request, I have tried to show a part of the plot above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Using  `Green` and `Red` *gradient colors* in the two intervals of interest

```
parts = Select[data, #] & /@ 
  {#[[2]] < -1 || 6 <= #[[2]] &, -1 <= #[[2]] < 4 &, 4 <= #[[2]] < 6 &};
colorfuncs = {Automatic, 
 Function[{x, y}, Blend[{Lighter@Lighter@Green, Darker@Green}, y]], 
 Function[{x, y}, Blend[{Darker@Red, Lighter@Lighter@Red}, y]]};

Show[ListPlot[#, ColorFunction -> #2, Joined -> True, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]&@@@ 
   Transpose[{parts, colorfuncs2}], GridLines -> {None, {-1, 4, 6}}, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False] /. Line -> Point
```

[image]

Replace `Lighter@Lighter@Green` and `Lighter@Lighter@Red` with `White` in `ColorFunction` to get

[image]

**Original answer:** FWIW

You can use `Style` on individual data points to color each point based on its second component:

```
styleddata = Piecewise[{{Style[#, Lighter@Lighter@Green], #[[2]] < -1}, 
 {Style[#,  Darker@Green], -1 <= #[[2]] <= 4}, 
 {Style[#, Darker@Red], 4 <= #[[2]] <= 6}, 
 {Style[#, Lighter@Lighter@Red], 6 <= #[[2]]}}] & /@ data;

ListPlot[styleddata, GridLines -> {None, {-1, 4, 6}}]
```

[image]